# How do I get a list in an android RecyclerView to update after an activity that modifies what it was showing?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've seen some RecyclerView examples that simply modify an item within the click listener. My problem is that I start an activity from a click on an item, and the activity can change or delete the clicked item from the list. So the view needs to be updated after the activity is finished. 
This code mostly from another developer passes the serialized item and position of the item to the activity as extra data. The position was intended to use to update the view later.

However, I found these comments:

"Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later. RecyclerView will NOT call onBindViewHolder again when the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method, and should NOT keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later (eg. in a click listener), use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated adapter position."

In the Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    final Item item = items.get(position);
    holder.itemTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.lay_item.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Item", item);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            context.startActivity (intent);
            // TODO is this the place to refresh the view?
            //holder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    });
}
```

and for the activity:

```
Item currentItem;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);

    currentItem = (Item)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Item"));
    position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
    ... 
}
```

I realize that the object held by the view is serialized into the extra data, so currentObject in the activity is not the same object.

I don't know why they did it like that. If that is the norm, please tell me how the list view is updated for changes to the object in the activity. If that is not the norm, how should it be done?
Therein lies the basis of the question, stated in the title:
How do I get a list in an android RecyclerView to update after an activity that modifies what it was showing?

Within the Activity, there is this click listener for the "save" button to update the database:

```
    btn_save.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // ... stuff that updates the item attributes from the view elements... 
            // Save it. It is this object that should then be in the list in the RecyclerView.
            try
            {
                MyApp.getDatabase().updateItem(item);
                // TODO: This might work if currentItem was actually the one in the list
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch (PersistenceException ex)
            {
                // notify user of failure
                Toast.makeText (EditItemActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.item_update_fail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                finish();
                return;
            }

            Toast.makeText(EditItemActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.item_update_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            finish ();
        }
    });
```

The adapter was created in the fragment like this (where "rv_items" is the RecyclerView):

```
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, getActivity());
        rv_items.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The Item class is declared as:
    class Item implements Serializable

Answer (score 1):

In general, any time you're talking about "modifying a RecyclerView", that's a hint that you're looking at things the wrong way. You should always think about modifying the **data**, and then realize that the RecyclerView is just one way to display that data. Of course, you'll need to call methods like `notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever you modify the data so that the RecyclerView can know to update its display to pick up the changes, but you should still always think about the data first.

That being said, the root of the problem here is that you need some way to uniquely identify your item in your list of data items. Generally, I'd lean towards using some sort of unique ID here (instead of position). Then, when your second activity finishes and returns its result, you can use the ID to update your data list and dispatch the changes to the RecyclerView.

With all that, you'd have something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String id = data.getStringExtra("id");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
                if (items.get(i).getId().equals(id)) {
                    // the item at position i was updated.

                    // insert your code here...

                    // at the end, notify the adapter
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understandable. Thanks. I changed so only the id is passed through as extra data. Then the object is fetched using the id. Where the item details activity is launched I call 'setActivityForResult()' instead of 'setActivity()', to be sure where the result comes from. However I never fixed the original issue because I have now changed to using a 'ViewModel' and 'LiveData'.